# Como puedo arreglar Exception ignored in: <function Image.__del__ at 0x0000021EB41D95E0>

Tags: python, imagen

Tengo una app que me esta generando un error al cerrarla. Durante su uso no hay inconveniente alguno.
El código sería algo así (RESUMIDO):

```
class Farfalla:
    def __init__(self,principal):
        self.inicio=principal
        self.inicio.title('Farfalla')
        self.inicio.geometry('340x450+300+50')#+500+50 ubicación de la ventana en la pantalla
        self.inicio.iconphoto(True,PhotoImage(file='mariposa2.png'))
        self.inicio.config(bg='#C3C3C3')
        self.inicio.resizable(width=0, height=0)
        self.logo=PhotoImage(file='./logo.png')
        self.lInicio=Label(self.inicio, image=self.logo, bg='#C3C3C3',)
        self.lInicio.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, rowspan=6)
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    inicio = Tk()
    app = Farfalla(inicio)
    inicio.mainloop()
```

Al cerrar la ventana me da este error

```
Exception ignored in: <function Image.__del__ at 0x0000016D06D6A5E0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MartinAriel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4017, in __del__
TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed
```

Donde puede estar el error?

Comment: El error está en un método (`__del__`) cuyo código no has publicado. Edita tu pregunta y añade ese método.

Comment: No tengo ningún método (`__del__` )en ninguna parte del código. Eso es lo raro

Comment: Tienes razón. El error están en tkinter. Probablemente a consecuencias de pasarlo algún parámetro con problemas. Lamentablemente el código que publicas está incompleto y no me es posible ejecutarlo.

Comment: Encontré el inconveniente 

`from IPython.terminal.pt_inputhooks import tk`

de una prueba que hice y no funcionó. Me quedo el modulo sin eliminar.